# Qt Android - "Building the android package failed!"

Tags: android, qt, ant

I am trying to program for Android with Qt.
But when I try to run my project the following error appears:

`Warning: Dependency not found: C:/Qt/5.3/android_armv7/plugins/platformthemes
Warning: Dependency not found: C:/Qt/5.3/android_armv7/plugins/platforminputcontexts
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.3
19:20:18: Der Prozess "C:\Qt\5.3\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" wurde mit dem Rückgabewert 14 beendet.
Fehler beim Erstellen/Deployment des Projekts AndroidTest2 (Kit: Android für armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.3.0))
Bei der Ausführung von Schritt 'Deployment auf Android-Gerät'
19:20:18: Verstrichene Zeit: 00:13.`

I really do not know how to solve this, I looked around, also on stackoverflow, but nothing
helped, I checked my ant-path in QtCreator and stuff like that.
Could anybody help me?
Thanks!!

Enno

Comment: Is `ant` correctly set in the Android configuration (and in the `$PATH`)? There's also (this bug)[https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-38651?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel] which was solved in subsequent 5.3.1 release.

Comment: Are you sure that the kit is setup correctly? Is qt installed correctly? Neither of these folders exist in 5.3.1

Comment: Hm I am actually not sure, to which files does the path point to?